# Fechar Activity se Ociosa

Tags: android, android-activity, timeout

Tenho uma aplicação e preciso que a `Activity` feche automaticamente se estiver ociosa, ou seja, se o usuário não tocar na tela durante 30 segundos, a `Activity` fecha automaticamente.
Enquanto o usuário estiver utilizando (tocando) a `Activity`, ela permanecerá aberta.

Estou utilizando o método `CountDownTimer`, porém mesmo que o usuário esteja utilizando o app, ela fecha.

Por favor, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu costumo criar aplicações para sistemas de totem interativos, que sempre necessitam de um `timeout`. Vou tentar explicar como eu faço isso:

Primeiro eu crio uma classe que estenda de `Application`, aqui vou chamar ela de `MyApplication`.

Dentro da `MyApplication`, colocaremos esses dois atributos:

`private static int seconds = 30;
 private static int timeOut = 30;`

Onde `timeOut` é o tempo que maximo que sua tela pode ficar ociosa, e `seconds` é o tempo que seu contador irá decrementar.

Feito isso, criaremos dentro da `MyApplication` um `TimerTask`. Algo assim:

```
private static class Task extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            stop();
           //Seu tempo acabou
        }
    }
}
```

Note como decrementamos nosso `seconds` ali.

Agora só falta criar as funçoes para o uso do nosso `Task`.

`private static Timer timer;
private static Task timerTask;`

```
  public void start() {
    stop();

    timerTask = new Task();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 1000, 1000);
}



public static void stop() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }

    if (timerTask != null) {
        timerTask.cancel();
    }

    refresh();
}

public static void refresh() {
    seconds = timeOut;
}
```

Voilà, agora você tem a função `Start` para iniciar seu contador, a função `Stop` para parar e a função `refresh` para atribuir o valor inicial ao contador.

Para o uso, basta chamar na sua `Activity` por: `MyApplication.getInstance().start()`

Lembre-se de fazer o `refresh` sempre que houver algum evento em sua aplicação, pode utilizar esse código para isto:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    MyApplication.refresh();
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    MyApplication.refresh();
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    MyApplication.refresh();
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    MyApplication.refresh();
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Só não esqueça de declarar seu `MyApplication` dentro da tag `<Application>` no seu manifesto.

`android:name=".MyApplication"`

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: muito obrigado pela sua excelente explicação e também pelos exemplos. Vou implementar em meu código, pois a função de minha aplicação é a mesma que você desenvolve: totem.  Acredito que me ajudará.  Muito obrigado

Comment: seu código funcionou perfeitamente.  Muito obrigado

Comment: Legal que tenha te ajudado! Abs